# VB.NET How to remove borders from menustrip?

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if it was possible to remove the borders from a menustrip in a form? As well as the blue background/shade when you hover over it. I looked through the properties, but found nothing. Here's an example of what I mean: https://gyazo.com/c04b8f944ddc973c7d24de1d88c91185

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I don't have much in the way of code, as I've tried most of the border, style, etc.. properties that work on other things such as text boxes, buttons, and none of it "exists". I'm basically trying to remove the white border that's shown on the edges, and bottom on the items in the menu. Not only that, but when I hover there's a slight shade of blue, but it's not a background color being changed. Sorry if it wasn't described correctly. I've looked through all the properties, and see nothing about borders or hover colors.

Comment: There's two ways you can do it: 1) override the painting behavior yourself and draw everything manually or 2) use a custom renderer control which you can bind your menustrip's Appearance property to and then use the custom editor to set all the colors. That's what I do and here's what I use: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62814/Fully-customizable-Menu-Tool-ContextMenu-and-Statu

Comment: Are you looking for a menustrip that is more in line with the default style of Windows?